# Example usages of an "arm" as a "subsidiary"

Tags: word-usage

I think an "arm" can refer to something like a "subsidiary" of a company.  Can you show me several examples, preferably in the internet?

To be clear, I'm not looking for "arms" as "weapon," or "arm's length rule," though both can be related to making a business.

Comment: Have you tried looking for examples of this on the internet yourself?

Comment: If you google "arm of the company", you will find many examples, including "[The UK arm of the company is lost, no direction, no plan and no leadership](https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Employee-Review-Axios-Systems-RVW6246498.htm)" and "[The financial services arm of the company grew considerably](http://www.related.com/our-company/ourhistory.aspx)" and "[Dr. Squire has led the research arm of the company](http://www.adastrarocket.com/aarc/board-of-directors)".

Comment: Thanks, I tried "arms subsidiary" "business arm" "arm company" etc etc but not that particular combination.  Feel free to laugh at someone who's so poor at English, but let me point out you actually needed a substantial working knowledge of English to come up with an effective search term.

Comment: @nodakai: Judging from your comment, you seem to have a substantial working knowledge of English :)  You should try Google's Ngram. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arm+of+the+company%2Carm+of+the+business&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carm%20of%20the%20company%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carm%20of%20the%20business%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano Thanks, I'm hoping a collocation dictionary in the future to evolve with such a technology.  But as of now, my Oxford Collocations Dictionary doesn't spend a single word on an "arm" which is not literally under your shoulder.